# How to convey the voice of an entity that fluidly switches from a single mind to multiple minds?

Tags: dialogue, voice

I am writing a sci-fi story. One of the character(s) is an intelligent fungus that spreads throughout an exoplanet as, biologically, a single individual.

My sources of inspiration for this character are an intelligent fungus from Arthur C. Clarke's *Rendesvouz With Rama*, and Planet the intelligent fungus from Sid Meier's *Alpha Centauri*. Specially the latter.

Planet is also a planet-spanning fungus. The neural network made by Planet's hyphae thinks and communicates as a single mind in a way that indicates a single consciousness, and Planet seems to think and operate with human speed.

This is where I depart from my inspirations. I want to add a layer of hard-scifi realism. Human synapses clock at 120 m/s at most (~270 mph). A fungal equivalent of a synapsis should be slower. Thus a signal might take close to two Earth days to reach its farthest point on the surface of an Earth-sized planet. This won't do for a single intelligence that reacts to its environment in a meaningful manner while still being "one". So rather, my planet-spanning neural network will have consciousness of varying levels of complexity forming all the time and in different locations, covering areas of different sizes.

Like processes in a computer network (a server farm?), such consciousnesses spawn as needed for a purpose. They will last for as long as necessary (from moments to millennia) and then can split, merge or be dismissed. Short term memory lasts as long as such a process lasts, but long term memory that is reusable by later consciousnesses also exists.

**And here I have a problem. When communicating with humans, how do I convey the dialogue with these consciousnesses without confusing the reader?**

I have considered an approach like the constantly plural voice of Legion (both the biblical group of demons and the similarly named character from the *Mass Effect* series of videogames), but that does not seem like a proper match when a single consciousness is operating over a given mass of mycelium. **But I also worry that switching from "I" and "me" to "we" and "us" (and back) mid-dialogue may sound inconsistent and confusing.**

Are there any examples of such a fluid pool of minds in any fiction, that I could use as a basis?

---

As to how communication with humans is possible, there is a plethora of ways. Some faster ones involve growing mycelium over an electronic board so the fungus can interface with a computer. Some slower, desperate ones involve forming a bulbous fruiting body over the span of a few days which can be used for haptic communication (as in the fungus pulsating it and a human poking on it to talk in Morse code).

Comment: That is an interesting question, but one not suited to this community. You're currently at a point in your writing process where you need to figure out how humans and those intelligent fungus would communicate. That is, you are currently asking yourself "what to write", as we call it. This community has decided that asking what to write is off topic on this site. I think a good place to ask that question would be https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com. Once you know what you want to write, we'll be happy to help you with *how* to write it.

Comment: @user482877 thank you for your feedback. However I know what I want to write. I have the narrative structure and plot all figured out. I know what this character needs to say, and when it needs to say - it's exactly the how that I am missing. On the other hand, I am the 3rd user in reputation in WorldBuilding and we would refer this question to Writing if it popped up there.

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other. When you say you are missing the how, what you mean is how they communicate. That is not a writing problem but a problem on the level of what you want to write. Example: In a story Peter wants to let Paul know that he is going to the party. Now the writer wonders whether he should have Peter send a text message, call Paul, or let Mary tell Paul. That is a problem of how Peter communicates, but is is a what to write problem. Before this what to write problem has been solved, there is yet no problem how to write how they communicate. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: I think that figuring out how the fungus communicates with humans is a worldbuilding problem.

Comment: You could copy the 'royal we' and capitalize We, Us, Our... so the reader knows the fungus isn't talking about itself and the humans when it uses 'we', for example.